# Getting youtube links from embedded youtube video on pages?

Tags: python, regex

Is there a regex to get youtube video links or ids from embedded youtube videos on webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find:
`"<object(.*)youtube.com/v/(.*)\"(.*)</object>"`

To convert to a link:
`replace("<object(.*)youtube.com/v/(.*)\"(.*)</object>", '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\\2">click here</a>', $str)`

[source](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/170154-convert-embed-youtube-videos-links-regexp.html#post848178)